# Intuitively, why should I expect a circle in the complex plane from the equation $\left|\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right| = c$?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry

I know how to prove that : ($c \in [0,1[$)

$$C = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \left|\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right| = c \}$$

is circle in the complex plane. To do so we can for example write $z = x+iy$ and use the brute force approach.

Also, it's worth mentioning that it's intuitive for me that
$$\{z \in \mathbb{C} : \left| z - z_0 \right| = c \}$$

represents a circle.

But I don't see at all why intuitively $C$ is a circle. So is it possible to understand geometrically why $C$ is a circle in the complex plane ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: What does intuition mean? How does intuition tell's you $y=ax+b$ is a line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going in steps:

1. $|\frac12 - z| = \frac c2$, or $|1 - 2z| = c$, is the intuitive representation of a circle.
2. $|1 - 2\overline{z}| = c$ is still a circle; we've just reflected it about the real axis.
3. Here's the tricky part. Replacing $\overline{z}$ by $\frac1z$ preserves the angle of a point but takes the reciprocal of the magnitude. This makes it an [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#Circle_inversion) in the complex plane, which also preserves circles. (Well, circles through the origin become lines instead, but our circle isn't one of those.) So $|1 - \frac2z| = c$ is still a circle.
4. Finally, going from $|\frac{z-2}{z}| = c$ to $|\frac{z-1}{z+1}| = c$ is just a translation by $1$.

Comment: Thank you,  this is the kind of intuition I was looking for !

Comment: really cute! (+1)

Comment: Nice job @Misha!

Answer (score 4):

Let's explore.
$$\bbox{
\left\lvert \frac{z - 1}{z + 1} \right\rvert = c
} \quad \iff \quad \bbox{
\frac{\lvert z - 1 \rvert}{\lvert z + 1 \rvert} = c
} \quad \iff \quad \bbox{
\left\lvert z - 1 \right\rvert = c \left\lvert z + 1 \right\rvert
} \tag{1}\label{NA1}$$
This only makes sense if $0 \lt c \in \mathbb{R}$.
Since $z \in \mathbb{C}$, we can write $z = x + i y$. Since $\lvert z \rvert = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, we have
$$\bbox{
\left\lvert \frac{z - 1}{z + 1} \right\rvert = c
} \quad \iff \quad \bbox{
\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + y^2} = c \sqrt{(x+1)^2 + y^2}
} \tag{2}\label{NA2}$$
Since $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c \gt 0$, both sides are positive, and we can square both sides:
$$\bbox{
\left\lvert \frac{z - 1}{z + 1} \right\rvert = c
} \quad \iff \quad \bbox{
(x-1)^2 + y^2 = c^2 (x+1)^2 + c^2 y^2
} \tag{3}\label{NA3}$$
Expanding and moving all terms to one side, we get
$$\bbox{
\left\lvert \frac{z - 1}{z + 1} \right\rvert = c
} \quad \iff \quad \bbox{
x^2 - 2 x + 1 + y^2 - c^2 x^2 - c^2 y^2 - 2 c^2 x - c^2 = 0
} \tag{4}\label{NA4}$$
The case when $c = 1$ is special, because then $\eqref{NA3}$ simplifies to $x = 0$, which is not a circle but a line (unless you say it is an infinite-radius circle centered at real $\pm\infty$).  In any case, let's continue the exploration with $0 \lt c \in \mathbb{R}$, $c \ne 1$.

We can collect the terms in $\eqref{NA4}$, getting
$$\bbox{
\left\lvert \frac{z - 1}{z + 1} \right\rvert = c
} \quad \iff \quad \bbox{
(1 - c^2)\left( (x + 1)^2 - \frac{4 x}{1 - c^2} + y^2 \right) = 0
} \tag{5}\label{NA5}$$
Because we already decided $c \ne 1$, this is equivalent to
$$\bbox{
\left\lvert \frac{z - 1}{z + 1} \right\rvert = c
} \quad \iff \quad \bbox{
(x + 1)^2 - \frac{4 x}{1 - c^2} + y^2 = 0 , \quad c \ne 1
} \tag{6}\label{NA6}$$
This is getting interesting. Compare to the equation of a circle of radius $r$ centered at $x = x_0$,
$$\bbox{ (x - x_0)^2 + y^2 - r^2 = 0 }$$
Now, if we choose
$$\bbox{ x_0 = \frac{2}{1 - c^2} - 1} , \quad \bbox{ r = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1 + c^2}{1 - c^2} \right)^2 - 1} }$$
we find that
$$\bbox{ (x - x_0)^2 + y^2 - r^2 = (x + 1)^2 - \frac{4 x}{1 - c^2} + y^2 }$$
Therefore,
$$\bbox[#ffffef]{ \bbox{
\left\lvert \frac{z - 1}{z + 1} \right\rvert = c
} \quad \iff \quad \bbox{
(1 - c^2)\left( (x - x_0)^2 + y^2 - r^2 \right) = 0
} , \quad \bbox{
z = x + i y
} \tag{7a}\label{NA7a} }$$
where
$$\bbox[#ffffef]{ \bbox{
x_0 = \frac{2}{1 - c^2} - 1
} , \quad \bbox{
r = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1 + c^2}{1 - c^2} \right)^2 - 1}
} , \quad \bbox{
c \gt 0 
} , \quad \bbox{
c \ne 1
} , \quad \bbox{
c \in \mathbb{R} 
} \tag{7b}\label{NA7b} }$$
and describes a circle of radius $r$ centered at $z = x_0$ on the real axis when $c \gt 0$, $c \ne 1$, and a line along the imaginary axis when $c = 1$.  No intuition or geometry needed, basic algebra suffices.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but IMO is a bad answer to the question asked. 
Saying "no intuition or geometry needed" shows that you didn't really address what the OP was asking. The OP explicitly said that he was looking for a geometric intuition, not the brute force analytical method that you used (which he was aware of).

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$
\eqalign{
  & \left| {{{z - 1} \over {z + 1}}} \right| = c\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad \left| {z - 1} \right| = c\left| {z + 1} \right|\quad  \Leftrightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Leftrightarrow \quad {\rm distance}\;\left( {x,y} \right)\;{\rm from}\;(1,0) = c\; \cdot \;{\rm distance}\;\left( {x,y} \right)\;{\rm from}\;( - 1,0) \cr} 
$$
which is another way to define a circle.

Thanks to @Rahul for indicating the actual attribution for such definition ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Circle_of_Apollonius )

Comment: +1. Which happens to be a line exactly when $c=1$.

Comment: How does that define a circle? I'm familiar with the classical definition of a circle: Distance to a given point is constant. How is distance to a point a multiple to distance to another point an intuitive definition of a circle?

Comment: What has that answer to do with intuition?

Comment: Thank you answer but I agree with @StefanLafon : "How is distance to a point a multiple to distance to another point an intuitive definition of a circle? "

Comment: @Stefan, dghkgfzyukz: It's not intuitive. But it's a classical theorem of Euclidean geometry. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Circle_of_Apollonius

Comment: @dghkgfzyukz  Ok, sorry for giving as "intuitive" what is instead a "classical" (ancient greek times) definition, within the series of definitions for the conics (as constant sum of distances from foci, constant difference.. etc.)

Comment: @GCab: Nice!  It looks like [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3084969/318422) just extends this (for no real reason or need, except me definitely not being a mathematician) to find the correspondence between Circle of Apollonius and a circle centered somewhere on the $x$ axis, transforming the equation to the more "intuitive" form ($(x-x_0)^2 + y^2 - r^2 = 0$ and the specific values of $x_0$ and $r$).  I do prefer your answer, by the way -- even more if you were to append a short note, something like "(See Wikipedia article on Circle of Apollonius for details.)" to your answer.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: thanks for the suggestion (and thanks to @Rahul): I added the reference to Apollonius. Your answer is wellcome to demonstrate analytically that (+1).

Answer (score 3):

Let's have $MA=kMB\iff \dfrac{MA}{MB}=k$ with fixed points $A,B$ and $k>0,k\neq 1$ a constant.

Then the locus of $M$ is a circle.

*Note: the case $k=1$ degenerates into a line, indeed $MA=MB$ is simply the perpendicular bisector of $[A,B]$.*

The original equation can be written $(\overrightarrow{MA})^2=k^2(\overrightarrow{MB})^2\iff (\overrightarrow{MA}-k\overrightarrow{MB})(\overrightarrow{MA}+k\overrightarrow{MB})=0$

So let's define $I,J$ the centroids $\begin{cases}\overrightarrow{IA}-k\,\overrightarrow{IB}=\vec 0 &:& I=\dfrac{A-kB}{1-k}\\\overrightarrow{JA}+k\,\overrightarrow{JB}=\vec 0&:& J=\dfrac{A+kB}{1+k}\end{cases}$

Then we get $((1-k)\overrightarrow{MI})((1+k)\overrightarrow{MJ})=0\quad$ and since $(1-k^2)\neq 0\ $ (not the degenerate case) then

> $\overrightarrow{MI}\cdot\overrightarrow{MJ}=0\iff$ $M$ is on a circle of diameter $[IJ]$

In the same way $\dfrac{|z-z_A|}{|z-z_B|}=k$ is strictly equivalent to the problem above while identifying $M$ to $z$ and $A,B$ to $z_A,z_B$ respectively.

Comment: Nice answer. At least trying to approach it from a (vector) geometry point of view.