# Determine complex numbers represented by points common to loci $|z| = 5$ and $|z-5|=|z|$

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

On a single Argand diagram sketch the loci |z| = 5 and |z-5|=|z|. Hence determine the complex numbers represented by points common to both loci, giving each answer in the exponential form.

I know that we have to draw a circle with centre at the origin and radius 5 for |z|=5 ,and then its circumference will be the required figure .For the second one,I am not sure what to do.How  then should I answer the second part of the question?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $|z-5|=|z|$ describes the set of points equidistant to $5$ and $0$ -- a line Re$(z)=2.5 $ -- not so convenient in exponential form

Comment: For the second one, consider $\dfrac {|z-5|}{|z-0|}=k$ this is an Apollonius circle if $k\neq 1$ and a perpendicular bissector else. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3085237/399263

Answer (score 1):

Write $|z-5|=|z|$ as $(z-5)(\bar z-5) = z\bar z$. Simplify, along with $|z|^2 =25$, to get,

$$z+\bar z = 5, \>\>\>\>\> z\bar z=25 \tag 1$$

Note that the first equation is also $Re(z) = \frac52$, which is the vertical line at $x=\frac52$ in the Argand diagram.

The points common to both $|z|=5$ and $|z-5|=|z|$ are the intersections between the two equations in (1), which can be combined as,

$$z^2-5z+25 = \frac{z^3+125}{z+5}=0$$

and yields two points given by $z^3=-125$, i.e.
$$z=5e^{\pm i \frac\pi3}$$

[image]

Comment: You should say that from $z^3=-125$ you exclude root $z=-5$.

Comment: @JeanMarie - good note. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider the second constraint.

Let $A=(5,0), B=(0,0)$ and $M$ be the generic point of the locus.

$$|z-5|=|z-0| \iff dist(M,A)=dist(M,B)$$

The set of such points $M$ is the perpendicular bissector of line segment $[AB]$.

Therefore, it is the line with cartesian equation $x=5/2$ and the Argand plane equation

$$z=x+iy=5/2+it \ \ \text{for any real} \ t  \tag{1}$$

We want those points that are such that (first constraint) $|z|=5$, meaning that

$$|z|^2=25=25/4+t^2 \iff t_0=\pm(5/2)\sqrt{3}$$

The argument of such a $z$ is (by reference to (1)) can be computed (as the two solutions are in quadrants 1 and 4) by :

$$\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})=\tan^{-1}\frac{t_0}{(5/2)}=\pm \tan^{-1}\sqrt{3}=\pm \frac{\pi}{3}$$

> Final answer : $z=5e^{\pm i\tfrac{\pi}{3}}$