# Modular equation with complex numbers: given $\displaystyle \Big\vert \frac{z-50}{z-2} \Big\vert = 5$ find $\vert z \vert $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I am asked the following question:

> Suppose $z$ is a complex number. Find $\vert z \vert$.
> $$\Big\vert \frac{z-50}{z-2} \Big\vert = 5$$

**The book's solution:**

Initially, I pretty much did the same as the book instructed, using all properties of modulus, substituting $\vert z \vert$ for $z \cdot z^*$ and so on (I'll just place the book's mark scheme):

[image]

**Second (?) solution:** I basically treated $z$ as an unknown:

$$\Big\vert \frac{z-50}{z-2} \Big\vert = 5$$

$$\frac{(z-50)^2}{(z-2)^2} = 25$$

$$z^2 -100z +2500 = 25z^2 -100z+100$$

$$z^2 = 100$$

$$\vert z \vert = 10$$

**My question:** I found that the answers are the same. But is this method valid in the first place? Is it ok for me to assume and treat z as an unknown variable?

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: You made several mistakes that just appear to cancel each other. For complex numbers, it is **not** true that $|a|^2 = a^2$. For example, $|i|^2 = 1$, but $(i)^2 = -1$. When you have $z^2=100$ in complex numbers, you get $z=10$ or $z=-10$. But $|z|=10$ in complex numbers has infinitely many solutions. Your second line doesn’t follow from your first, and your last line doesn’t follow from the penultimate one. It’s not that you “treat[ed] $z$ as an unknown variable”, it’s that you messed up the arithmetic of complex numbers.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin so basically all issues derive from the fact that $z^2$ is not $z \cdot z$ but $z \cdot z^*$, correct?

Comment: No, $z^2$ is **still** $zz$. The problem is that $|z|$ is not $\sqrt{z^2}$, it’s $\sqrt{z\overline{z}}$. So $|z|^2 = z\overline{z}$ in complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The first method looks okay.  The second method is not a correct approach.

$$\left|\frac{z-50}{z-2}\right|^2=\frac{z-50}{z-2} \cdot \frac{\overline{z}-50}{\overline{z}-2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Moebius transformations are easily inverted.

[image]

$$ \frac{z-50}{z-2}  = 5 \omega  $$
where $\omega = e^{it} $ for real $t$ and has magnitude $1$

Coefficient matrix is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1&-50 \\
1& -2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Any multiple of the inverse matrix works,
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
-2&50 \\
-1& 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

or

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2&-50 \\
1& -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$  z = \frac{2(5\omega) - 50}{5 \omega - 1} $$
$$  z = \frac{10\omega - 50}{5 \omega - 1} $$
$$  z = 10 \frac{\omega - 5}{5 \omega - 1} $$

The values of $z$ lie on some circle, maybe it is centered on the origin, maybe not. For $\omega=1$ we get $z = -10.$  For $\omega=-1$ we get $z = 10.$  For $\omega=i$ we get $z = 10 \frac{5+12i}{13}.$  $\omega=-i$ we get $z = 10 \frac{5-12i}{13}.$ Note that (5,12,13) is a Pythagorean triple

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here : [$\dfrac{MA}{MB}=k\ $ is a Apollonius circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3085237/399263)$\iff \dfrac{|z-z_A|}{|z-z_B|}=k$

Applying to your problem $z_M=z,\ z_A=50,\ z_B=2$ and $k=5$

The diameter $[IJ]$ is given by $\begin{cases}z_I=\dfrac{z_A-kz_B}{1-k}=\dfrac{50-10}{-4}=-10\\z_J=\dfrac{z_A+kz_B}{1+k}=\dfrac{50+10}{6}=10\end{cases}$

Therefore $M$ is on the circle of centre $O$ and radius $10$.

Answer (score -3):

I disagree with the other answers, perhaps because I **meta-cheat**.

What the OP did, without realizing it, is assume that $z$ maybe expressed as $x + iy$.  The **meta-cheating** idea, is that if the problem is solvable, then the problem is **still** solvable if

$$y ~\text{is assumed to equal} ~0.$$

In effect, perhaps without realizing it, the OP treated the problem like a math puzzle rather than a math problem.  It was **not a coincidence** that the OP's method worked.

There seems to be confusion about the underlying mathematical basis for this specific meta-cheating.

I am asserting that the method is flawless when solving for |z| with respect to the complex variable z, as long as long as any satisfying values for the value to be solved for, (in this case |z|), each occur at least once in whatever
**restricted domain** that you are exploring.

The only reason that the meta-cheating involves restricting the domain to $\mathbb{R}$ is for ease of use. The principle will mathematically hold, regardless of what restricted domain you investigate, as long as |z| takes on all pertinent values there.

Naturally, the specific meta-cheating process for this problem involves identifying candidate values for z that may not work against the original equation.

Anytime you have a problem asking for you to solve for |z|,
then **if** there is only one value for |z| to be determined, the method can not fail.  This is because if no real solutions in the meta-cheated equation are uncovered, then you know immediately that in this specific problem, you must abandon the meta-cheating idea.

This answer (in effect) answers why the OP's (invalid) method works.  It is because he restricted the domain to be investigated to $\mathbb{R}$, and because all values to be solved for, |z|, each occurred at least once in the restricted domain.

---

A comment/question was asked:

For what values of $a,b,c$ will the meta-cheating approach lead to the wrong conclusion re solving for $|z|$ re

$$\frac{|z-a|}{|z-b|} = c.$$

Exploring, I squared both sides.  This *may* result in candidate values for $z$ that do not solve the original equation.

This resulted in

$$|z|^2(c^2 - 1) + 2\text{Re}(z)(a - bc^2) + (b^2c^2 - a^2) = 0.$$

In order for the meta-cheating idea to fail:

(1) 
There must be at least two distinct values for |z|, such that each of them will have at least one underlying value of $z$ that satisfies the equation.

(2) 
At least one of the two distinct values for |z| must never occur in the restricted domain of $z \in \mathbb{R}.$

Looking at the general problem, I actually have **no opinion** when the meta-cheating would fail, re the above two conditions both occurring.

**Edit**
However, given the latest downvote, I really can't help myself here:

In the above equation, which explored when the meta-cheating would or would not fail with respect to the equation

$$\frac{|z-a|}{|z-b|} = c$$

It is immediate that when $(a - bc^2) = 0$, which is the case in the OP's problem, you are mathematically **guaranteed** that there can only be one satisfying value for $|z|$, which is the value being asked for.

In such a situation, per discussion previously in this answer, the meta-cheating approach **can not** fail.

Come to think of it, when $(a - bc^2) = 0$, if the problem has any solutions at all, the locus of points $z$ that provide the appropriate value of $|z|$ will have to be a complete circle centered at the origin, which (further) guarantees that the locus of points will cross the $x$-axis.

Comment: But $y\ne 0$! The answer is a circle in the complex plane. Assuming that $y=0$ gives two solutions, $z=\pm 10$ - which is very much wrong. The OP's method is wrong.

Comment: Okay, addressing the edit, you are stating that if you assume that $z$ is real, than the OP's method, and answer is correct. While this is not wrong, it has no place here as $z$ is not real and the whole point of the problem is that $z$ is complex.

Comment: It worked because as you said "all satisfying values have the same norm". But this is just sheer luck. If the two on the denominator were replaced by a three, then not all the values would have the same modulus.

Comment: If we set $z=w-1$, the equation in $w$ becomes $\frac{|w-51|}{|w-3|}=5$. The solutions will be $|w-1|=10$. Solving it for reals will lead to the quadratic $w^2-2w-99=0$, won’t be so clear to see how you turn that into something “usable”, any more than it would have if the OP had gone from $z^2=100$ to the *correct* conclusion of $z=10$ and $z=-10$.

Comment: The method does not work. You tried the problem $\frac{|z-5|}{|z-3|}=5$. You found two real solutions $\frac{10}{3}$ and $\frac{5}{2}$. Clearly both of these work (why would they not). But you then claim that $|z|=\frac{5}{2}$. This is not true. For starters $z=-\frac{5}{2}$ does not work, and the solution is certainly not a circle of radius $\frac{5}{2}$ centered at $0$. All your method does is find the two real solutions, this says nothing about the complete solution set: $|z-\frac{35}{12}|=\frac{5}{12}$.

Comment: Your restricted domain is the reals. Of course you can search for real solutions. But it is clearly a complex variable question about identifying complex valued solutions. Simply saying the method works for real valued solutions is not a good answer to a complex analysis problem.

Comment: What do you mean there is only one solution for $|z|$? Are saying if $|z|=const$? aka it is a circle centered at $0$? Then yes, if the solutions is a circle centered at $0$ then the method will work. But you will have to prove this before hand. Your method clearly didn't work for the case in edit 3 and the final answer was wrong. If you go through a proof that the solution set must be a circle centered at $0$, and then find one real solution and infer the full solution set, then fine, but you have not done that.

Comment: Okay, let us say in the original question you found the solutions $z=\pm 10$. But you do not know that the solution set is a circle centered at $0$ as you have not proved it. From your two solutions, what further solution can you discover?

Comment: Yes, but you do not know that $|z|$ only takes one value. From your method, if you got the solutions $-10$ and $10$ you cannot infer any more solutions.

Comment: So you are making an assumption based on the phrasing of the question. That is not a good method, and is not mathematical.

Comment: The answer to that question is very simple: The solution is a circle centered at $0$. Your answer barely mentions that and includes a lot of irrelevant and incorrect content.

Comment: Okay, enlighten me. Given a problem $\frac{|z-a|}{|z-b|}=c$, for what values of $a,b,c$ will your method work? Your method makes an assumption that $|z|=const$ which  is untrue in general and you have provided no way to verify this assumption.

Comment: I do not understand either of your conditions. What does this mean: "At least one of the two distinct values for $|z|$ must never occur in the restricted domain of $z\in\mathbb{R}$"? Moreover, you still have not provided a way of testing your assumption. When you assume $z$ is real, you find two real solutions - from here you cannot infer any more. Even if you find that $z=\pm 10$ you can claim that $|z|=10$ in general without proving your claim of $|z|=const$.