Loci of $C$ such that $AC=2BC$, given that $A$ and $B$ are fixed points
I was solving this complex numbers problem:

Find the loci of $|z+1|=2|z-1|$.

I solved this problem by substituting $z=x+iy$ and after some manipulations the answer that I got is the circle with center $O(\frac53,0)$ and radius $\frac43$.
But I'm interested in the geometric interpretation of this problem (finding the loci using only geometric constructions). Given the fixed points $A=(-1,0)$ and $B= (1,0)$ we are looking for the loci of a point $C$ where $AC=2BC$,

If $C$ lies on $AB$, it is easy to see that this point is $(\frac13,0)$. Now we have $\frac{AC}{BC}=2$. But if this point is not collinear with $A$ and $B$, according to angle bisector theorem in $\triangle AEC$, I observed that $EC$ should be the angle bisector of $\angle AEB$. From here I don't know how to continue and conclude the loci is a circle passing $C$ and $D$.

See my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3085237/399263

The desired locus is called the Apollonius Circle. It is the circle that has diameter the segment joining the leg of the inner angle-bisector and the leg of the outer angle-bisector ($C$ and $D$, respectively in your figure).
See this link for more details.
Half-proof:
First notice that points $C$ and $D$ are the two unique points on the line $AB$ with the desired ratio division, where one lies inside the segment $[AB]$ and one lies outside of it (in particular, $C$ and $D$ are independent of the choice of point $E$). We prove that the desired locus is the circle with diameter $[CD]$.
For any point $E$ for which $|EA|/|EB|$ has the desired ratio, it must hold that $EC$ is the inner angle-bisector of $\Delta EAB$ and $ED$ is the outer angle-bisector of $\Delta EAB$. These imply that $\angle CED = 90^\circ$. Thus, $E$ lies on the circle with diameter $[CD]$. This proves that any such desired point $E$ lies on this circle.
For the proof to be complete, one also has to prove the following. For any point $E'$ on this circle, $|E'A|/|E'B|$ is equal to the desired fix ratio. Proofs for this can be found in the link I provided above.

Thanks a lot! Now I found this proof.

I believe that the proof there is incomplete, because it does not justify the following claim it makes. "For any P on the circle, the internal and external bisectors of angle APB pass through (the fixed points) M and N."

It was hard to follow for me as well. But I believe it used exterior angle bisector theorem for $N$.  Additionally, if we choose $P$ to be below $AB$ it will result in the lower semi-circle.

When one selects a point $P$ for which the only thing known is that it lies on the circle with diameter $[MN]$, one does not (yet) know that $PM$ and $PN$ are angle-bisectors. Hence, one cannot use the exterior angle bisector theorem. In fact, showing that $PM$ and $PN$ are angle bisectors are ultimately what one wants to prove in order to show that point $P$ is of the property that $|PA|/|PB|$ is equal to the desired ratio.

I perceived this proof as follow:  Given the ratio is $r$, one can easily find $M$ and $N$ on $AB$ and on its extension respectively such that they satisfy this ratio.  Now assume that $P$  is a point that satisfies this ratio $r$ but is not collinear with $A$ and $B$. According to angle bisector theorem $PM$ should be internal bisector of $\angle APM$ and according to exterior angle bisector theorem $PN$ should be exterior bisector of $\angle APM$.  Hence  we have $\angle MPN= 90^{\circ}$  for the fixed points $M$ and $N$. (Note, this explanation is for finding the loci from scratch).

That is precisely the argument I already provided in my answer, and it is half of the proof. It only proves that any point with the desired ratio condition lies on the circle. However, for a complete characterization of the Apollonius Circle, one also has to prove the other direction, namely, to prove that any point on the circle is a point with the desired ratio condition. (To understand better, ask yourself the following question: How can I make sure that the locus of points with the desired ratio condition is this circle + some other line in the plane?)

Sorry for misunderstanding I got your point now!
